# Coordinates on Button Click javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can any one plz tell me where i am wrong.I want to get coordinates of button on click but it give me error

**js/main.js (1) :ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $**

Button:

```
 <input type="button" style="margin-left: 80px;margin-top: 80px;"  id="theButton"  value="A button" />
```

J Query

```
 var jq = $('#theButton');
 var position = jq.offset();
 alert('x: ' + position.left + ', y: ' + position.top);
```

it doesn't show me anything

Comment: Did you include jquery in your HTML page?

Comment: are you including jQuery?

Comment: Apparently not, or after the script he's using

Comment: Ya i included jquery.var init = function () {
   
    console.log("init() called");
};   and it is callled...
window.onload = init;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jq = $('#theButton');
    var position = jq.offset();
    alert('x: ' + position.left + ', y: ' + position.top);
});
```

Add any version of `jquery` first in the head sections before adding your `main.js`
like:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>`

Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PSpvT/

Comment: but it worked the otherway..i had to add $(document).ready(function(){});
and write rest code in init().then it worked..can u xplain me why it worked this way

Comment: i want to add it in onClick

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the below:

```
var jq = $('#theButton');
```

Try

```
var jq = document.getElementById("theButton");
```

**jQUERY SOLUTION:**

```
$(function() {
  var jq = $('#theButton');
 var position = jq.offset();
 alert('x: ' + position.left + ', y: ' + position.top);
});
```

Comment: This will give error `jq.offset() is undefined` as it is function of `jquery`

Comment: then you shoud put your code in a DOM Ready jquery function as above in jquery solution